# Converting between different Int sizes in Swift 2

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get this piece of code working in Swift 2:

```
func +(left: Character, right: Int) -> String {
    return String(UnicodeScalar(String(left).utf16[0] + right))
}
```

It was working with old versions of Swift.

First, I transformed `utf16[0]` in `utf16[0].value` but it says that `Binary operator + cannot be applied to operands of type Int16 and Int`.

Also having `right` as an Int16, doesn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work with `utf16`.

```
func +(left: Character, right: Int) -> String {
    let scalars = String(left).utf16
    let value = scalars[scalars.startIndex].value as Int
    return String(UnicodeScalar(value + right))
}
```

It seems more natural with `unicodeScalars`.

```
func +(left: Character, right: Int) -> String {
    let scalars = String(left).unicodeScalars
    let value = Int(scalars[scalars.startIndex].value)
    return String(UnicodeScalar(value + right))
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't compile as of Xcode 7 beta 6 (Int16 is not convertible to Int). The other does compile though.

Comment: I rewrote it as a one-liner. Note that you can access the first index of the scalars collection with `first`:  `return String(UnicodeScalar(Int(String(left).unicodeScalars.first!.value) + right))`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using:

```
func +(left: Character, right: Int) -> String {
    return String(UnicodeScalar(Int(String(left).utf16.first!) + right))
}
```

Comment: It's very similar to your one liner which I didn't see until I had worked out my solution.

Comment: The strange thing is that conversion from CodeUnit to Int succeed, but from Int16 fails!

Comment: That is, if you use `.value` it fails.

Comment: Yes.  That is what took me so long.  I was chasing that problem for a while.  It is strange because you can init an `Int` with an `Int16`.